# How to link an android device (or its account) in a restricted way to my primary google account?

Tags: google-account, google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I have an Android powered car multimedia unit that I would like to link somehow to my google's account, so I could send locations from `Google maps` directly from my PC by clicking the "Send to your phone" button on the location description pane shown in the Google Maps.

At the same time I don't want this device to be logged into this account to prevent any potential data leaks.

Switching between accounts on a PC is not a convenient option.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You can send locations not only to your own account but also to friends (or the Google account of your car).

Comment: @Robert, I believe you meant "Share" button. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: "At the same time I don't want this device to be logged into this account to prevent any potential data leaks." - This prevents what you are trying to do, in order to make the Send to your phone option work your Google account must be on the device, you can't just "link" a device to it, you could potentially add the Google account and do not sync any information except Maps although I don't know if that would work.

Comment: "Send to a friend" or "Send to your phone" - if it works it does not matter - have you tried it? Anyway you have to use multiple accounts as a Google account on Android can't be limited to just Google Maps.

Comment: @Robert, then how to link the device to account so it has no access to all data in the account, uses _another_ password and it appears in the list of your phones?

Comment: I wrote clearly **multiple accounts** not one account. What you want is not possible.